# Finding an element whose minimal polynomial is an Eisenstein polynomial

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

If we have an extension of number fields $L/K$ and $Q$ is a prime ideal of $L$ lying over $P$, do we know for certain if there exists an element $\pi \in Q \setminus Q^2$ whose minimal polynomial over $K$ is an Eisenstein polynomial?
If you don't mind, I would prefer arguments that do not explicitly involve local fields. Thank you very much in advance!

EDIT: if the answer is yes, can we ask for the minimal polynomial of $\pi$ to also have degree e(Q/P)?

Comment: For an explicit example, take $L = \mathbf{Q}(\sqrt[4]{50})$ and $K = \mathbf{Q}$, where (for $p = 5$) one has $e = f = 2$. Since the (unique) intermediate field $\mathbf{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ is unramified at $p$, *any* $\pi = Q \setminus Q^2$ must generate the field $L$, but then the minimal polynomial of $\pi$ is degree $4$ and the constant coefficient is divisible by $N(Q^2) = 5^2$.

Comment: Thank you! What happens if I do not ask for an Eisenstein polynomial, just for a polynomial whose coefficient are all in the ideal $P$? (I'll add an edit)

Comment: 1. If the set of primes above $P$ are $Q_i$, then the minimal polynomial of any element of $\cap Q_i$ has coefficients in $P$, so every element in $\cap Q_i \setminus Q^2$ will have this property. 2. I already explained in my previous comment that any element in $Q \setminus Q^2$ in the example has degree $4$. 3. Changing questions after they have been answered is poor form.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I didn't know that! I'm a new user. Thank you very much, anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer should be no, in general. After localizing, we'd get an extension $L_{Q}/K_{P}$ of local fields with uniformizer $\pi$. This extension however may not be totally ramified, hence the minimum polynomial of $\pi$ may not be Eisenstein. Here we are using the fact that an extension $L/K$ of local fields is totally ramified if and only if the minimum polynomial of every uniformizer $\pi_L$ is Eisenstein over $K$.

Comment: But saying that not every uniformizer has an Eisenstein minimal polynomial does not preclude the fact that there is one uniformizer with Eisenstein polynomial, right?

Comment: After you pass to the local fields, if the minimum polynomial of one uniformizer is Eisenstein, so is the minimum polynomial of every uniformizer.

Comment: I see. Thank you! I guess this does not work in the case  of allowing the constant term of the minimal polynomial to be in $P^2$,right?

Comment: This argument does not work: If one takes some totally ramified extension $L/K$ and follows it by an unramified extension $M/L$, then for the overall extension $M/K$, at least some uniformizers (those that are originally uniformizers of $L/K$) will have minimal polynomials Eisenstein, despite the fact that $M/K$ is not totally ramified.

Comment: @PavelČoupek thanks, I think you're right.